# tmux - split-window with custom environment variables

Tags: tmux

I want to split the current tmux window and have it inherit my current environment.

I need to do this programmatically so I can't do it through some predefined config file.

Simply put, I want to do something like,

```
tmux split-window my-binary
```

my-binary is in my current PATH but not the usual one (it seems tmux just goes through my bash_profile).

Is it possible? Or do I have to start bash and setup the env before starting my-binary?

Answer (score 0):

To split a window that will run an instance of your default shell, use the `env` command that runs whatever is configured as `default-command` in your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
tmux split-window "env FOO=bar $(tmux show-options -vg default-command)"
```

Comment: As far as I can tell this inherits the environment from the tmux session (as `split-window` would normally do) and in addition sets the environment variable `FOO`. This does *not* inherit the environment of the *currently active window*, which is what the OP is asking for.